# Effect of umask on text files

Tags: linux, file, unix, permissions, umask

I understand how umask works, at least a basic level, when dealing with the permissions of an executable file or directory. However, I struggle when it comes to how umask applies its rules to  text files.

For example, consider the umask 037. On newly created executables or directories I understand that the permissions would arise from a simple subtraction (777-037 = 740). My  question though is then how does the apparent subtraction work for determining the permissions on say a text file who's default permissions would be 666.

To be clear how is the subtraction done (666-037 = 637?) obviously having an executable text file makes no sense, and according to some examples I have carried out I know that that the file permissions in such a case should work out to 640.

How is this subtraction done? How do we arrive at 666-037 = 640?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not subtraction. It's masking: Boolean "AND" using the bitwise complement ("NOT") of the `umask`. So, think of the `umask` as the bits that should be removed from the mode.

```
Create mode  0666 (octal)                         = 110110110 (binary)
Mask          037 (octal) = 000011111 (binary)
(Complement of mask)      = 111100000 (binary)    = 111100000 (binary) &
                                                    ---------
Result       0640                                   110100000
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations

Comment: Thank you for both the quick reply with worked out example and literature!

Comment: The only thing I might add is that the umask itself is negated before combining using the "AND" operation.

Comment: Haha. You're totally correct. Apparently I just did that part in my head and didn't even notice. I've updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks.